# How I can bind these queries at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, subquery

Could somebody tell me how I can bind these queries in one?

```
$campaign_id = CampaignAdvertising::where('advertising_id', $advert_id) 
                                  ->value('campaign_id'); 

$company_id = Campaign::where('id',$campaign_id)->value('company_id'); 

$admin_id = Admin::where('company_id',$company_id)
                 ->where('id',$user->id) ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the collection returned from queries but can not merge queries.

You will need to right raw queries with UNION to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$data = DB::table('campaignadvertising')
->join('campaign', 'campaign.id', '=', 'campaignadvertising.campaign_id')
->join('admin', 'admin.company_id', '=', 'campaign.company_id')  
->select('campaign.*', 'campaignadvertising.*', 'admin.*' )
->where('campaignadvertising.advertising_id', $advert_id)
->where('admin.id',$user->id)
->get();
```

Comment: tnx! I made like this if(count(CampaignAdvertising::join('campaigns','campaign_advertising.campaign_id','=','campaigns.id')->join('companies','campaigns.company_id','=','companies.id') ->join('admins','admins.company_id','=','companies.id')                                   ->where('campaign_advertising.advertising_id',$advert_id)
                                    ->where('admins.id',$user->id)
                                    ->get()) > 0)
Actually i wanted to know if i have something in my db so i put it into "if" 
Anyway tnx for answer